# postgresql display correlation on columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlation

So I have a few tables, and I would like to see how I could present the correlation of one of the columns compared to the rest as a column in my table.

For Example, let's say I have 2 tables:

- Batting(key:Team, battingAverage, slugging, etc.)
- Record(key:Team, wins, losses)

If I want a table whose output is

```
attribute      | correlation
battingAverage | .025
slugging       | .005
...
```

How would I go about achieving this? I know I can use a CORR function to find the correlation between two columns, but I'm confused as to how I apply it to an entire column, and how I can display that column and its correlation into a row.

Right now I'm attempting to hard code it in using (values (),(),...) but I'm getting an error saying that my subquery is returning multiple rows when used as an expression, but "SELECT" only shows up once in my query and I can't see any expressions either.

Here's my mock up query right now (my project has nothing to do with baseball, but I made up this for example sake)

```
SELECT attributes.attribute, (values 
    (CORR(Record.wins,Batting.BattingAverage)),
    (CORR(Record.wins,Batting.slugging)),
    (CORR(Record.wins,batting.OBP)),
    (CORR(Record.wins,batting.HomeRuns)))
AS correlation
FROM Batting LEFT JOIN Record ON Batting.Team = Record.Team,(values
    ('Batting Average'),
    ('Slugging'),
    ('OBP'),
    ('Home Runs')) attributes(attribute)
GROUP BY attributes.attribute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a row per column, you'll have to generate these somehow. You are trying to do this with a cross join (which would have been slightly more readable had you called it `CROSS JOIN` instead of `,`). But you are not relating the select clause to the desired attribute.

```
SELECT 
  attributes.attribute,
  CORR(Record.wins,
       case attributes.attribute
         when 'Batting Average' then Batting.BattingAverage
         when 'Slugging' then Batting.slugging
         when 'OBP' then Batting.OBP
         when 'Home Runs' then Batting.HomeRuns
       end
      ) AS correlation
FROM Batting 
JOIN Record ON Batting.Team = Record.Team
CROSS JOIN (values
    ('Batting Average'),
    ('Slugging'),
    ('OBP'),
    ('Home Runs')) attributes(attribute)
GROUP BY attributes.attribute;
```

I'm not quite sure however, whether building a cartesian product infuences the correleation. I think it doesn't because all rows get multifold with the same factor, but I am not familiar with statistics and corelation calculation.

I would rather keep it easy and safe:

```
SELECT 'Batting Average' AS attribute, CORR(r.wins, b.BattingAverage) AS correlation
  FROM Batting b JOIN Record r ON b.Team = r.Team
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Slugging' AS attribute, CORR(r.wins, b.slugging) AS correlation
  FROM Batting b JOIN Record r ON b.Team = r.Team
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OBP' AS attribute, CORR(r.wins, b.OBP) AS correlation
  FROM Batting b JOIN Record r ON b.Team = r.Team
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Home Runs' AS attribute, CORR(r.wins, b.HomeRuns) AS correlation
  FROM Batting b JOIN Record r ON b.Team = r.Team
```

A simple alternative should be `UNPIVOT`. I've never used it, however, but it should be easy to look up the syntax. I guess `UNPIVOT` would actually be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: That second code block is very straight forward, I didn't consider just generating each row at a time before since there aren't that many attributes. Thank you!